# HANIMEX Automatic Zoom Lens C- Macro 1:4.5 F=80-200mm

Tags: lens, lens-mount, equipment-identification

[image]Could anyone tell me what camera body this lens will fit please? It's been packed away with my dad's old Praktica SLR but it doesn't seem to fit that. It's a "HANIMEX Automatic Zoom Lens C- Macro 1:4.5 F=80-200mm"

It does have an Olympus cap on it but wasn't sure if that was just a spare he'd put on at some point.

Answer (score 3):

It is an Olympus OM mount for older film cameras like the Olympus OM-1.

With the right adapter the lens could be used on many modern digital cameras.

[image]

Comment: Just do not expect too much of most third party consumer zoom lenses that old.